# Expanding the roomba to auto-delete self-accepted-answered questions with low views, low scores, and only 1 answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, self-answer, auto-delete

<sup>For background info, read about the [current roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/244519) that runs automatically to delete questions.</sup>

This is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to add one more rule set on when questions will be auto-deleted by the [Community User ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) as stated below  :

---

**If the question is more than `60` days old, and ...**

- has only 1 answer which was posted by the same user who asked the question
- the self-answer is accepted
- both the question and answer have a score of <= 0
- has a view count < the age of the question in days / 2 <sup>*(this is more strict than the other roomba's)*</sup>

... it will be automatically deleted

---

There are currently :
[248,766](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/248371/count-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0-an) questions that meet the above standards for auto-deletion on Stack Overflow.
[4,259](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/248371/count-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0-an) on Super User
[3,034](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/248371/count-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0-an) on Server Fault
[2,900](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/248371/count-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0-an) on Ask Ubuntu
[146](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/248371/count-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0-an) on Web Applications
[35](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/248371/count-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0-an) on English Language & Usage

Why should we add this?

- Clean up the sites from questions that are likely no help to anyone else and probably not even any help to the OP anymore
- This is a convert way to spam/promote your things. All you have to do to stop your seed question and the answer from being deleted is to accept your answer and hope that the question doesn't get enough close votes which could make it eligible for deletion with the roomba for closed questions. If no one upvotes the question or answer within 60 days, it's likely both the question and answer aren't that helpful to anyone else in the future.
- There is no community approval of these questions/answers. Visitors to the site that may possibly end up on these low-viewed questions will see the accepted answer and possibly take that to mean the answer actually works. But only 1 person was involved in this. No upvotes from others, experts, in the community agreeing with the answer the questioner posted.

If you'd like to see some of the questions that would be auto-deleted with this roomba script, please refer to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/248370/top-2500-of-single-answered-self-answered-accepted-questions-with-score-of-0), which is for Stack Overflow. To see the results for another site, simply type that site name in the switch site input box.

Comment: you might want to read [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077)

Comment: Your view count condition is more strict than the other roomba, not les so.

Comment: I am a bit concerned that self-answered posts on the less popular tags will get vacuumed mainly because less popular tags get less traffic (so less chance for upvotes and less chance for views).

Comment: Same for less-popular sites. Maybe the questions that aren't already closed that meet these criteria should go into one of the review queues. That way they'll get in front of more people and the good ones will get votes while that bad ones will get closed.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce They're not really egligible for VLQ, though, and the CV queue on SO is (still) _really_ long.

Comment: Bullet 3 in your rules says <=0 but your query returns only <0

Answer (score 5):

Can we PLEASE have this? ... and apply it to non-self answered questions, too. [This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/319098/deletable-questions?TagsContain=%25%25&TagsDoNotContain=xyzzy) exposes the true gem of these questions that we're not deleting on SO:

Here are a bunch for your enjoyment:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708107
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174636
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377975
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860299
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683367
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154390
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803813
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373065
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197919
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845539

I'm glad that the person who asked the question got enough use out of the answer to decide to click the green checkmark. No one else will ever get use from these questions again.

## Delete them.

Comment: These don't match the question's criteria which is that the question be self-answered. Of course you could make your own suggestion that we expand things to include non self-answered questions under some criteria.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oh, whoops. I missed that the OP specified self-answered questions.